# How to get logs of eventarc events

Tags: google-cloud-functions

In the documentation, the firebase resize extension has the piece of code

```
exports.onimageresized = onCustomEventPublished(
    "firebase.extensions.storage-resize-images.v1.complete",
    (event) => {
      logger.info("Received image resize completed event", event);
      // For example, write resized image details into Firestore.
      return getFirestore()
          .collection("images")
          .doc(event.subject.replace("/", "_")) // original file path
          .set(event.data); // resized images paths and sizes
    });
```

only when I check for that log in the function logs, there is nothing, only a create operation log(for when the function was deployed). Weird thing is the function still writes to firestore, I actually thought it was not firing.
Where are the eventarc logs read from, I cannot seem to find them

Comment: Taio, do let me know if my recommendations were useful.

Answer (score 1):

The following types of audit logs are available for Eventarc:

- Admin Activity audit logs Includes "admin write" operations that
  write metadata or configuration information. You can't disable Admin
  Activity audit logs.
- Data Access audit logs Includes "admin read" operations that read
  metadata or configuration information. Also includes "data read" and
  "data write" operations that read or write user-provided data.

To receive Data Access audit logs, you must [explicitly enable](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access#config-console-enable) them.
Eventarc audit logs use the service name eventarc.googleapis.com.
Eventarc audit logs use the resource type audited_resource for all audit logs.
You can view audit logs in Cloud Logging by using the Google Cloud console, the Google Cloud CLI, or the Logging API.
To view directly using the Cloud console follow the below steps:

1. In the Google Cloud console, go to the Logging> Logs Explorer page
   Select an existing Cloud project, folder, or organization.
2. In the Query builder pane,In Resource type, select the Google Cloud
   resource whose audit logs you want to see and in Log name, select
   the audit log type that you want to see.

If you're experiencing issues when trying to view logs in the Logs Explorer, see the [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-explorer-interface#troubleshooting) information.
Also check the documentation for [functions calling eventrac](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/eventarc) and [supported events](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/reference/supported-events).

Comment: Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)
and 
[Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know,I do not have knowledge on ChatGPT and GPT, from the official Google documents I have taken the above information and tried to answer the OPs question.I have provided the links from where I have refered the content in answer.Please let me know if there was any other mistake and apologies if I have missed anything.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know,I do not have knowledge on ChatGPT and GPT, I have taken help from official Google documentation and my knowledge and understanding on the products to frame the answer and help OP.I have never used or will use any AI tools.